# Reading a Blob File with Spark

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage

I have a very large file in blob but cannot read it with spark.

## Reading the all_crimes from my Azure blob storage

```
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\ .builder\ .appName("KF7032 Assessment by W22030982")\ .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")\ .getOrCreate()


all_crimes = spark.read.csv("https://myblobname.blob.core.windows.net/newcontainer/AllCrimesSampleData.csv?sp=r&st=2022-12-01T17:37:55Z&se=2023-02-01T01:37:55Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=tnVclTnREPdBSra08zRXI8xS%2FF6DZ3ty9007mOMMdss%3D")

all_crimes.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduce same in my environment and got the below results:**

You can read multiple files using this code. Copy the access key from the storage account past in `<access_key>` as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Code:**

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net","<access_key>")

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load("wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/folder/")
```

**Output:**

[image]